# Tinylog capture System Error output stream to log file

Tags: java, logging, error-logging, tinylog

I am using Tinylog for logging everything in my java application. I capture all the exceptions and logs them.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tinylog</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinylog-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tinylog</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinylog-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am writing the logs on Console as well as on File. Here is my `tinylog.properties` file

```js
writer1= console
writer2 = rolling file
writer2.file = /var/log/oozie-monitor-log/monitor-{count}.log
writer2.charset  = UTF-8
writer2.append   = true
writer2.buffered = false
writer2.backups  = 15
#writer1.level = debug
#writer2.level = debug
writer2.policies = daily
writer1.format = {date: HH:mm:ss.SSS} {level}: {message}
writer2.format = {date: HH:mm:ss.SSS} {level}: {message}
```

Now the issue is that there are some system error and warning that is not getting captured by Tinylog.
For example I see below logs on the Console but these logs are available in log file

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/neeleshnirmal/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.6/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/neeleshnirmal/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

So my question is how can configure Tinylog to capture the System error stream also?

Answer (score 1):

tinylog does not provide any adapter for forwarding console output to the logging framework. It is possible to develop such an adapter by just a few lines. However, it won't help you, because it would create an infinite loop in your use case as you use also a console writer for outputting log entries into the console. Therefore, such hypothetical console adapter would also capture console output from the console writer and send again to the console writer.

Instead, I recommend to fix the warnings. Your warning examples are quite easy to fix: Remove slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar, and the log4j JAR from the classpath. Afterwards you can add [slf4j-tinylog](https://tinylog.org/v2/download/#slf4j) and [log4j1.2-api](https://tinylog.org/v2/download/#log4j). This will not only fix the warnings, but also forward all logging entries from SLF4J and Log4j to tinylog.